# Two different menus for Top App Bar and Bottom App bar with Navigation Components

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack, androidx, android-bottomappbar

I was trying out Android [Navigation Architecture Component](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/index) and was also looking into [Material design](https://material.io/) guidelines. I really got inspired by the [design](https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-bottom.html?image=https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.googleapis.com%2Fspec-host-backup%2Fmio-design%252Fassets%252F1axQM_eykG-5a7MzFhupQyQN0qc02du6k%252Fplacement-top-app-bar-bottom-primary.png#behavior) below:

[image: Top and bottom app bar]

For the top toolbar I can set it by `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` and then in `MainActivity`:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

But while trying it out I cannot figure it out how to implement menus on both Top and Bottom app bars for different fragments, specially for bottom app bar.

**For example**, I want to show ***a favorite icon on bottom app bar only*** on `DetailFragment`, but on `MainActivity`, it should be gone.

My current codes:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController);


        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(view -> Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show());


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        return Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host).navigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

**MainFragment**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Button buttonOne = view.findViewById(R.id.button_one);
        buttonOne.setOnClickListener(Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.detailFragment));
    }

}
```

**DetailFragment**

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

    public DetailFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_appbar" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

mobile_navigation.xml

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.example.MainFragment"
        android:label="fragment_main"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/toAccountFragment"
            app:destination="@id/detailFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:name="com.example.DetailFragment"
        android:label="fragment_account"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail" />
</navigation>
```

**menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

**bottom_appbar_menu.xml** for `DetialFragment` only

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_bottom_fav"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite"
        android:title="@string/action_favorite"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Any help is appreciated.

---

#### Updated with possible solution:

This is what I'm able to come up with but is not satisfied as I don't know if it's the write way to do it. I'm posting a possible solution:

1- MainActivity

```
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController);
```

2- Creating two different menus for bottom app bar (I didn't tried adding menu items dynamically), one with a blank menu xml for `MainFragment` and another one that contains a favorite icon for `DetailFragment`.

For simplicity, overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu` in `MainActivity` rather than overriding it with the `MainFragment`:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    bottomAppBar.replaceMenu(R.menu.bottom_menu_blank);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

3- Thanks to [@ʍѳђઽ૯ท](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52484521/2519748) for letting me know about `replaceMenu` method of Bottom App Bar. In `DetailFragment` use `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` and override `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    BottomAppBar bottomAppBar = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.bottom_appbar);
    bottomAppBar.replaceMenu(R.menu.bottom_menu_fav);
}
```

If anyone has a better way then please do let know.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `onCreateOptionsMenu()` for the `Toolbar` as usual: (*Kotlin*)

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_first, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```

Then declare the `Toolbar` inside `onCreate()` and use `setSupportActionBar()`:

```
val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.myToolbar)
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

And after that, `replaceMenu()` will do the trick: (Inside `onCreate()`)

```
val bottomBar = findViewById<BottomAppBar>(R.id.bottomAppBar)
bottomBar.replaceMenu(R.menu.menu_main)
```

---

Note that if you wanted to use `BottomSheetFragment` for the `NavigationView` opening, you'll need `setSupportActionBar` in order to set `menu`s for the `BottomAppBar` and I couldn't still find a way to fix this.

Comment: Thank you for the input but it's not a full answer, however +1 for this. Full ans? Ex: I have to use `BottomAppBar#replaceMenu` in on `MainActivity`'s method `onCreateOptionsMenu`. To show a different menu on a fragment, again I have to use `BottomAppBar#replaceMenu` with a different menu xml file. To do that, I have to use `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` and override `onCreateOptionsMenu` within fragment. However, I was looking for more specific answer if anyone has any other than what I've written. But again, thank you.

Comment: That's all of it actually. Your question title asks what I answered and what's related to answer but it seems like you need to add menus inside `Fragment`. Well, yeah. use `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` and `onCreateOptionsMenu` inside the `Fragment` and it will show what you're looking for. However, I've added a note you may wanna consider reading it.

Answer (score 0):

To have more than one Toolbar (or BottomAppBar), you will have to inflate the other one manually. When you call **setSupportActionBar()** and **onCreateOptionsMenu()**, you are essentially doing this:

```
private boolean inflateBottomAppBar() {
    BottomAppBar bottomAppBar = findViewById(R.id.bottomAppBar);
    Menu bottomMenu = bottomAppBar.getMenu();
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_bottom, bottomMenu);
    for (int i = 0; i < bottomMenu.size(); i++) {
        bottomMenu.getItem(i).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                return onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
            }
        });
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Where **R.id.bottomAppBar** is the id of the **BottomAppBar** and **R.menu.menu_bottom** is the id of the menu items.

Call this method in your **onCreateOptionsMenu()** after you inflate the main toolbar and you will be good to go. All the item clicks will be handled normally by the **onOptionsItemSelected()** method.

This will also work if you are making two or more regular toolbars.