# Top Toolbar Menu + BottomAppBar Menu + BottomNavigationDrawerFragment Just like Material Design

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-menu, navigation-drawer, android-bottomappbar

What I want to achieve is like this image (***Without top `NavigationView` though***) but with `Toolbar` Menu +  `BottomAppBar` Menu + `BottomNavigationDrawerFragment` exactly like material design:

[image]

I could manage the `BottomAppBar` menu by `replace()` ([My Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52483927/two-different-menus-for-top-app-bar-and-bottom-app-bar-with-navigation-component)):

```
val bottomBar = findViewById<BottomAppBar>(R.id.bottomAppBar)
bottomBar.replaceMenu(R.menu.menu_main)
```

Which allow me to inflate menu for the `BottomAppBar` and used below codes plus `onCreateOptionsMenu()` for the `Toolbar` Menu and `setSupportActionBar()`:

```
val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.myToolbar)
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

**The point is**, in this [tutorial](https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/implementing-bottomappbar-behavior-fbfbc3a30568) (*for example*), he used `setSupportActionBar(bottom_app_bar)` for setting `SupportActionBar` on the `BottomAppBar`. So, if we use `setSupportActionBar(bottom_app_bar)` for the `BottomAppBar`, it will show the `BottomNavigationDrawerFragment` + Menus **are handlable on the Bottom Side.**

**But, what about `Toolbar` and menus?** `Toolbar` + menu items won't be handlable nor showing up if we use `setSupportActionBar(bottomAppbar)`.

The things that I have tested are:

- Might sound ridiculous but used two `setSupportActionBar()` for both `Toolbar` and `BottomAppBar`
- Even tried to inflate two menus by `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method but none worked.

**The question is**, How can we have Top `Toolbar` Menu + `BottomAppBar` Menu + `BottomNavigationDrawerFragment` all together?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hopefully, I have found the answer. So if we want to create such layouts (Without Top `NavigationDrawer` - `view`) Here are the steps:

Declare the `Toolbar` as usual:

```
val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.myToolbar)
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

Override `onCreateOptionsMenu` **with the Top `Toolbar` menu**:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.top_menu, menu)
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}
```

Use the following for handling `BottomBar` menus and replacing a new `Menu` in Bottom of the app & showing `BottomSheetFragment` when `NavigationIcon` selected:

```
val bottomBar = findViewById<BottomAppBar>(R.id.bottomAppBar)
bottomBar.replaceMenu(R.menu.bottom_menu)
bottomBar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
        val bottomNavDrawerFragment = BottomNavigationDrawerFragment()
        bottomNavDrawerFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, bottomNavDrawerFragment.tag)
    }
bottomBar.setOnMenuItemClickListener { menuItem ->

        when (menuItem.itemId) {
            R.id.search_Action ->{
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
         true
    }
```

And finally, Overriding `onOptionsItemSelected()`:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    when (item!!.itemId) {

        R.id.action_settings -> {

            startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, SettingsActivity::class.java))

        }

        R.id.changeView -> {
            toast("Test")

        }
    }
    return true
}
```