# How to set title in app bar with Navigation Architecture Component

Tags: android, android-layout, androidx, android-architecture-navigation

I was trying out Navigation architecture component and is now having difficulties in setting the title. How do I set the title programmatically and also how it works?

To clear my question, let's have an example, where, I've set up a simple app with `MainActivity` hosting the navigation host controller, the `MainFragment` has a button and on clicking the button it goes to `DetailFragment`.

The same code from another question of [multiple app bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52483927/two-different-menus-for-top-app-bar-and-bottom-app-bar-with-navigation-component) on stack-overflow.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Setting up a back button
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        return Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host).navigateUp();
    }
}
```

**MainFragment**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Button buttonOne = view.findViewById(R.id.button_one);
        buttonOne.setOnClickListener(Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.detailFragment));
    }

}
```

**DetailFragment**

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

    public DetailFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_appbar" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**navigation.xml**

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.example.MainFragment"
        android:label="fragment_main"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/toAccountFragment"
            app:destination="@id/detailFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:name="com.example.DetailFragment"
        android:label="fragment_account"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail" />
</navigation>
```

So when start my app, **the title is "MainActivity"**. As usual it shows the `MainFragment` that contains the button to go to `DetailFragment`. In the `DialogFragment` I've set the title as:

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Detail");
```

**First Problem:** So clicking the button on the `MainFragment` to goto `DetailFragment`, it does go there and the title changes to "Detail". But on clicking the back button, the **title changes to "fragment_main"**. So I added this line of code to `MainFragment`:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    // ...

    //Showing the title 
    Navigation.findNavController(view)
      .getCurrentDestination().setLabel("Hello");
}
```

Now the while returning back from `DetailFragment` to `MainFragment` the title changes to "Hello". But here comes the **second problem**, when I close the app and start again, the title changes back to "MainActivity" though it should be showing "Hello" instead, know?

Ok, then adding `setTitle("Hello")` in `MainFrgment` is not working too. For example, the activity starts and the title is "Hello", go to `DetailsFragment` and press the back button again, the title goes back to "fragment_main".

The only solution is to have both `setTitle("Hello")` along with `Navigation.findNavController(view).getCurrentDestination().setLabel("Hello")` in `MainFragment`.

So what is the proper way to show the title for fragments using Navigation Component?

Comment: possibly duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50599238/dynamic-actionbar-title-from-a-fragment-using-androidx-navigation/53830472

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic ActionBar title from a Fragment using AndroidX Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50599238/dynamic-actionbar-title-from-a-fragment-using-androidx-navigation)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As others are still participating in answering this question, let me answer **my own question** as APIs has changed since then.

First, remove `android:label` from the fragment/s that you wish to change the title of, from within `navigation.xml` (aka Navigation Graph),.

Now you can change the title from with the `Fragment` by calling

```
(requireActivity() as MainActivity).title = "My title"
```

But the preferred way you should be using is the API [`NavController.addOnDestinationChangedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#addOnDestinationChangedListener(androidx.navigation.NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener)) from within `MainActivity`. An Example:

```
NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
// compare destination id
    title = when (destination.id) {
        R.id.someFragment -> "My title"
        else -> "Default title"
    }

//    if (destination == R.id.someFragment) {
//        title = "My title"
//    } else {
//        title = "Default Title"        
//    }
}
```

Comment: In case you want no title at all, you cannot provide `null` or an empty string. Instead you have to set the `destination.label` to `" "`. I added this as an example in your code (should be visible after peer review of my changes)

Comment: @muetzenflo this has been fixed starting on Navigation UI "2.3.0-alpha04"

Comment: Or you can set directly destination.label and the appBar label changes. The `OnDestinationChangedListener` has to be set before calling `NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(...)`.

Comment: `(requireActivity() as MainActivity).title` does not change the label, even after removing the label from the Navigation Graph. Perhaps the API functionality has recently changed.

Comment: Or just add labels to all fragments in the navigation app graph, and set `title = destination.label`, as in: `findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments -> title = destination.label }`

Answer (score 60):

It's actually because of:

```
android:label="fragment_main"
```

Which you have set in the xml.

> So what is the proper way to show the title for `Fragment`s using
>   Navigation Component?

`setTitle()` works at this point. But, because you set label for those `Fragment`s, it might show the label again when recreating the `Activity`. The solution will probably be deleting `android:label` and then do your things with code:

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("your title");
```

Or:

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("your subtitle");
```

In `onCreateView()`.

---

**Found a workaround:**

```
interface TempToolbarTitleListener {
    fun updateTitle(title: String)
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), TempToolbarTitleListener {

    ...

    override fun updateTitle(title: String) {
        binding.toolbar.title = title
    }
}
```

Then:

```
(activity as TempToolbarTitleListener).updateTitle("custom title")
```

Check this out too:[Dynamic ActionBar title from a Fragment using AndroidX Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50599238/dynamic-actionbar-title-from-a-fragment-using-androidx-navigation)

Comment: I have already tried this and the outcome is if I don't use `Navigation.findNavController(view).getCurrentDestination().setLabel("Hello")` in the `MainFragment` then the title will remain "Detail". And don't know why, someone down voted the question :p.

Comment: I want to be clear here, adding `setTitle` along with `Navigation.findNavController(view).getCurrentDestination().setLabel("Hello")` seems to be the only way to get the title, even if I start the app or press the back button. So aren't there any viable way with a single line of code? Ok, let me update the question.

Comment: So, there's is problem with Navigation component.

Comment: Manually editing the title bar, or assuming the contents of `getCurrentDestination` will get it things of sync with the NavController. The correct solution is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50599238/dynamic-actionbar-title-from-a-fragment-using-androidx-navigation/54504353#54504353

Answer (score 23):

You can use this code in your fragment if you don't specify your app bar(default appbar)

```
(activity as MainActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Your Custom Title"
```

Remember to delete the `android:label` attribute in your navigation graph

Happy code ^-^

Comment: The key for me was to **delete** the `android:label` **attribute** from my Fragment in the navigation xml file. Then I was able to dynamically change the title of my Fragment by using `toolbar?.title = "my new name"`.

Answer (score 15):

From experience, [NavController.addOnDestinationChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#addOnDestinationChangedListener(androidx.navigation.NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener))

Seems to perform well. My example below on my MainActivity did the magic

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener{ controller, destination, arguments ->
        title = when (destination.id) {
           R.id.navigation_home -> "My title"
            R.id.navigation_task_start -> "My title2"
            R.id.navigation_task_finish -> "My title3"
            R.id.navigation_status -> "My title3"
            R.id.navigation_settings -> "My title4"
            else -> "Default title"
        }

    }
```

Comment: for anyone else being as stupid as me and wondering why it is not working: you have to add `supportActionBar?.title = title` at the bottom to apply the title to the actionbar

Comment: You can also set title with `destination.setLabel()` but it has to be before calling the `        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(...); method.
`

Answer (score 14):

There is a much easier way to achieve this nowadays with Kotlin and `androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx`:

```
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val navController: NavController
        get() = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this,R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController) // <- the most important line
    }

    // Required by the docs for setupActionBarWithNavController(...)
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp() = navController.navigateUp()
}
```

That's basically it. Don't forget to specify `android:label` in your nav graphs.

Comment: This is the right answer!

Answer (score 9):

You can use the navigation graph xml file and set the label of the fragment to an argument.
Then, in your parent fragment, you can pass an argument using SafeArgs (please, follow the guide on https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args to set up SafeArgs) and provide a default value to avoid the title being null or empty.

```
<!--this is originating fragment-->
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
        android:name=".ui.FragmentA"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_a">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/fragmentBAction"
            app:destination="@id/fragmentB" />
</fragment>

<!--set the fragment's title to a string passed as an argument-->
<!--this is a destination fragment (assuming you're navigating FragmentA to FragmentB)-->
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
    android:name="ui.FragmentB"
    android:label="{myTitle}"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_b">
    <argument
        android:name="myTitle"
        android:defaultValue="defaultTitle"
        app:argType="string" />
</fragment>
```

In originating Fragment:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
     String text = "text to pass as a title";
     FragmentADirections.FragmentBAction action = FragmentADirections.fragmentBAction();
     action.setMyTitle(text);
     Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action);
}
```

FragmentADirections and FragmentBAction -
These classes are autogenerated from IDs in your nav_graph.xml file.
In 'your action ID + Action' type classes you can find auto-generated setter methods, which you can use to pass arguments

In your receiving destination, you call auto-generated class {your receiving fragment ID}+Args

```
FragmentBArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments()).getMyTitle();
```

Please refer to the official guide at
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args

Comment: Could you complete your suggestion with the commands needed to provide an argument to xml file using SafeArgs?

Answer (score 5):

```
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
```

> Don't forget to specify **android:label** for your fragments in your nav graphs.

To navigate back:

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, null)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I've spent a couple of hours trying to do a very simple thing such as changing the bar title of a detail fragment when navigating from a particuler item on a master fragment. My daddy always said to me: K.I.S.S. Keep it simple son.
setTitle() crashed, interfaces are cumbersome, came up with a (very) simple solution in terms of lines of code, for the latest fragment navigation implementation.
In the master fragment resolve the NavController, get the NavGraph, find the destination Node, set the Title, and last but not least navigate to it:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

private void navigateToDetail() {

```
NavController navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(FragmentMaster.this);
navController.getGraph().findNode(R.id.FragmentDetail).setLabel("Master record detail");
navController.navigate(R.id.action_FragmentMaster_to_FragmentDetail,null);
```

}

Comment: Thank you man. It is very effective and simple :)

Comment: Why not *simply* use setTitle correctly? if you set it in each fragment's onCreate it shouldn't crash.

Answer (score 3):

**android:label="{title_action}"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/FirstFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/FirstFragment"
        android:name="com.example.contact2.FirstFragment"
        android:label="@string/first_fragment_label"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment"
            app:destination="@id/SecondFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/SecondFragment"
        android:name="com.example.contact2.SecondFragment"
        android:label="{title_action}"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_SecondFragment_to_FirstFragment"
            app:destination="@id/FirstFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
        <argument
            android:name="title_action"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Comment: val args = Bundle()

Comment: args.putString("title_action", "My Custom title")

Comment: findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_SecondFragment_to_FirstFragment, args)

Answer (score 2):

The API may have changed since the question was asked, but now you may indicate a reference to a string in your app resources in the navigation graph label.

[image]

This is pretty helpful if you want a static title for your fragments.

Comment: what if want to reuse this fragment and need to change the label? How will I do it programatically

Answer (score 2):

delete detatil fragment's label in navigation graph xml file.
then pass the prefered title through arguments to destination fragment which needs title like so.
The First Fragment code - Start point

```
findNavController().navigate(
            R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_descriptionFragment,
            bundleOf(Pair("toolbar_title", "My Details Fragment Title"))
        )
```

as you see I sent as pair in arguments bundle when navigating to Destination Fragment
so in your Destination Fragment get title from arguments in onCreate method like this

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        toolbarTitle = requireArguments().getString("toolbar_title", "")
    }
```

then use it to change Main Activity's title in onCreateView method like this

```
requireActivity().toolbar.title = toolbarTitle
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to include AppBar in each screen.
To avoid code duplicates, create a helper, that builds AppBar, taking the title as a parameter. Then invoke the helper in each screen class.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be this:

```
fun Fragment.setToolbarTitle(title: String) {
    (activity as NavigationDrawerActivity).supportActionBar?.title = title
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update title with either label in navigation xml or exclude labels and set with `requiresActivity().title` Supports mixing the two ways for screens with and without dynamic titles. Works for me with a Compose UI toolbar and Tabs.

```
    val titleLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
    findNavController().addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
        destination.label?.let {
            titleLiveData.value = destination.label.toString()
        }
    }

    (requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(object: Toolbar(requireContext()) {
        override fun setTitle(title: CharSequence?) {
            titleLiveData.value = title.toString()
        }
    })

    titleLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { 
        // Update your title
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyway few of those answers I tried did not work for then I decided to do it the old Java way in Kotlin using interface

Created an interface as shown below.

```
interface OnTitleChangeListener {
   fun onTitleChange(app_title: String)
}
```

Then made my activity to implement this interface as shown below.

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnTitleChangeListener {
    override fun onTitleChange(app_title: String) {
    title = app_title
    }
}
```

How on my fragment's on activity attache I this this

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    this.currentContext = context
    (context as HomeActivity).onTitleChange("New Title For The app")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The simple solution:**

**Layout**

```
androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
  
  androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    fragment
      androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
```

**Activity**

```
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, layoutRes)
    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
    
    val controller = findNavController(R.id.nav_host)
    val configuration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.navigation_home,
            R.id.navigation_dashboard,
            R.id.navigation_notifications
        )
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(controller, configuration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(controller)
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be helpful if you would like to change the title of Toolbar programmatically with low cohesion code between Activity and Fragment.

```kotlin
class DetailsFragment : Fragment() {

    interface Callbacks {
        fun updateTitle(title: String)
    }

    private var listener: Callbacks? = null

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        // keep activity as interface only
        if (context is Callbacks) {
            listener = context
        }
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        // forget about activity
        listener = null
        super.onDetach()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        listener?.updateTitle("Dynamic generated title")
    }

}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), DetailsFragment.Callbacks {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun updateTitle(title: String) {
        supportActionBar?.title = title
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### September 4, 2021

**Using Kotlin** in my case this is solution. use this code in MainActivity

```
 val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)
     navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
                destination.label = when (destination.id) {
                    R.id.homeFragment -> resources.getString(R.string.app_name)
                    R.id.roomFloorTilesFragment -> resources.getString(R.string.room_floor_tiles)
                    R.id.roomWallTilesFragment -> resources.getString(R.string.room_wall_tiles)
                    R.id.ceilingRateFragment -> resources.getString(R.string.ceiling_rate)
                    R.id.areaConverterFragment -> resources.getString(R.string.area_converter)
                    R.id.unitConverterFragment -> resources.getString(R.string.unit_converter)
                    R.id.lenterFragment -> resources.getString(R.string.lenter_rate)
                    R.id.plotSizeFragment -> resources.getString(R.string.plot_size)
                    else -> resources.getString(R.string.app_name)
                }
            }
            NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(...)
            NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

My own simple solution at last date library. Before calling navigate do as:

```
findNavController().findDestination(R.id.yourNavFragmentId)?.label = "Your title"
```

then navigate to your fragment

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.yourNavFragmentId)
```